# Attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, attributeerror

When I start the Discord Bot, it says `Attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'`

Here is my code:

```
async def on_member_join(member):

    channel = member.guild.system_channel

    background = Editor("sfondo.jpg")
    profile_image = await load_image_async(str(member.avatar.url))

    profile = Editor(profile_image).resize((150, 150)).circle_image()
    poppins = Font.poppins(size=50, variant="bold")

    poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=20, variant="light")

    background.paste(profile, (325, 90))
    background.ellipse((325, 90), 150, 150, outline="white",stroke_width=5)

    background.text((400, 260), f"WELCOME TO {member.guild.name}", color="white", font=poppins, align="center")
    background.text((400, 325), f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}", color="white", font=poppins_small, align="center")

    file = file(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="sfondo.jpg")
    await channel.send(f"Hello {member.mention}! Welcome to **{member.guild.name}")
    await channel.send(file=file)
```

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: To add more details to Sandy's comment - if you're using Discord.py version 1.7.3 then you should use `member.avatar_url` ; if you are using 2.0 then it's indeed `member.avatar.url` so please, check your version or if you don't need 2.0 functionality - try with `avatar_url`

Comment: Hey NeM, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*). As well, please include the full traceback of the error you are receiving. This will help others better understand the problem you are facing and will allow them to better assist you with it. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`member.avatar` is a string. It's a filename for the avatar.

You can get the avatars from `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/YOUR_USER_ID/YOUR_AVATAR_ID.png`

Try this :)

```py
avatarURL = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{member.id}/{member.avatar}.png"
```

Just as a hint for errors such these: If "Attributeerror: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'" raises, try to print it out. Then you will know, if it's already that what you want.